# Help need for specific boolean logic

Tags: language-agnostic, logic, boolean

```
CaptchaIsExist    CaptchaIsValid   =   Result
--------------    -------------       --------
   true                false        =    false

   Any other variations             =    true
```

Now how to write logic for having these results ? It looks simple but i think not enough.

Comment: Result = !(CaptchaIsExist && (!CaptchaIsValid));

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative to @Binary Worrier's solution:

```
bool Result = CaptchaIsValid OR NOT CaptchaIsExist
```

I think this expresses the logic more naturally, i.e. it conveys the intended logic when you read it.

Comment: Doesn't this result in `true` when `CaptchaIsValid=true` and `CaptchaIsExist=false`, or am I missing something?

Comment: If captcha does not exist, testing for its validity may fail. I think it's better to reverse the test order, assuming the language uses short-circuit evaluation.

Comment: @Binary Worrier: yes, it's supposed to - there are 3 out of 4 cases where the result should be TRUE and only one specific case where it should be FALSE, i.e. CaptchaIsValid=FALSE AND CaptchaIsExist=TRUE. (Note: if you apply De Morgan's Rule to your expression you get my expression, i.e. they are equivalent.)

Comment: @Paul R - is it also equals to (not CaptchaIsExist) or CaptchaIsValid ?

Comment: @AnyOne: yes, the order of evaluation doesn't really matter, provided these are just simple boolean values.

Answer (score 2):

Just specify the condition for `false` and apply `not` to it...

```
not (CaptchaIsExist && not (CaptchaIsValid))
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it is really simple.

```
bool Result = not (CaptchaIsExist and not CaptchaIsValid)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(not CaptchaIsExist) or CaptchaIsValid
```

Answer (score 0):

In C-like pseudocode:

```
if (CaptchaIsExist && !CaptchaIsValid) then
    return false;
else
    return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Boolean result = ((CaptchaIsExist && !CaptchaIsValid)) ? false: true;
```